# missing FROM-clause entry for table "f" for every attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm trying to run this code but this returns the above error.
I am trying to join two subqueries of the same table.

```
select 
      (lead(f.topup_date)  over  (partition by(f.id_user)  order by f.topup_date desc))  as  datepre,
       f.topup_date::timestamp  -  lead(f.topup_date::timestamp) 
       over (partition by(f.id_user) order by  f.topup_date desc),
       case when  f.topup_value>=20  then  'Y' else 'N' end,
       LEAD(temp.dt)  OVER( PARTITION BY  temp.id_user 
       ORDER BY temp.topup_date DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED 
       FOLLOWING),
      temp.division
FROM
(
          SELECT  (max(CASE WHEN f.topup_value >= 20 THEN f.topup_date  END) 
          OVER(PARTITION BY f.id_user ORDER BY f.topup_date DESC ROWS BETWEEN 
          0 PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING )) AS dt
          , f.topup_value::float / t1.topup_value::float AS division
          , t1.id_user
          , f.topup_date
        FROM topups t1
        JOIN topups as f USING (seq) 
) temp
```

Comment: You have no `f` in the `FROM` clause for the outer query.  It is undefined.

Comment: The 2nd last line "join topups as f using (seq)" it has f, that doesn't count? If so, then how do i write it?

Comment: . . No.  That `f` is only in scope in the subquery.

Comment: Just remove the aliases from the outer select and be sure you have included all the columns you need in the subquery.

Comment: Thank you Sir! By the way I tried joining temp with f and t1 , it worked as well.